# Unable to pull docker image from artifactory repo to Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I deployed kubernetes cluster with Weave CNI and so far I am able to deploy pods as needed. Now we are trying pull the docker images from articatory, but somehow its not working. getting the below error. surprisingly I am able to pull/push images from AWS ECR repo. Just baffling why we are failed to pull images to kubernetes cluster from artifactory which does not have any restrictions nor authentication. able to the images from this artifactory to regular docker VM's(which are running outside kubernetes cluster):

```
Version:

Client Version: v1.17.2
Server Version: v1.17.2

Host OS:
Centos 7.7

CNI:
Weave
```

Error:

**Trying to pull repository artifactory.gns.rms-internal.com/rms-docker-pr-local/sdp/rms/model-platform/model-engine-kubernetes ... **

**Get https://artifactory.internal.com/v1/_ping: dial tcp :443: connect: no route to host**

Appreciate any inputs or suggestions.

Thanks,
CS

Comment: Have you read this https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-GettingStartedwithArtifactoryProOn-Prem. You probably need a subdomain. You can also try to push your own  images to it - assuming its not just a cache for a remote docker repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is with a network, you have to remove all unused [networks](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/):

```
$ docker network prune
```

Then set the bit option on.

```
docker -> deamon.json -> bip
```

Just add `"bip": " xxx.yyy.zzz.vvv/ww"` line to `deamon.json` .
Restart docker:

```
$ docker restart
```

Docker is creating sub-networks on the same range that your private registry .

Take a look here: [pulling-images-issue](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/522), [bridge-networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/custom-docker0/), [docker-compose-subnet](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/4336),
[docker-pulling-issue](https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/218).

Take a look also on: [artifactory-on-prem](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-GettingStartedwithArtifactoryProOn-Prem).

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much. yep, after executing docker network prune its working.